# How read multiple column but with DISTINCT value from one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have a table like this:

```
    ID      OrderID    Date                     Name         Engineer
    3870    12302   2016-07-19 11:29:30.547 Popescu Bogdan      Yes
    4459    12302   2016-07-25 13:02:52.657 Popescu Bogdan      Yes
    3868    12302   2016-07-19 11:26:36.593 Popescu Bogdan      Yes
    3869    12302   2016-07-19 11:27:05.797 Popescu Bogdan      Yes
    4127    12302   2016-07-20 12:10:56.527 maria madalina      Yes
    4483    12302   2016-07-25 14:01:31.147 andrei vasile       Yes
    4538    12302   2016-07-25 18:58:34.007 vasilica vrabie     Yes
```

I want to get Date, Name and Enginner but with DISTINCT NAME. I want just Popescu, maria, Adnrei, Vasilica with Date, Name and Egineer

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
select DISTINCT NAME, [Date], Enginner 
from myTable
```

Also you can try

```
select NAME, [Date], Engineer from myTable where
ID in (Select max(ID) FROM myTable group by Name)
```

[image]

Comment: Work for me just for one column selected

Comment: @Vladut:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: IS ok, but if i have "WHERE     (OrderID = 12136)" how can i do?

Comment: I want to select DISTINCT name but when in but a specific id, i miss to put that in description

Comment: @Vladut:- If you want to select it with a specific Id then simply add it to the where condition like: `select * from myTable where
ID in (Select max(ID) FROM myTable WHERE OrderID = 12136 group by Name)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Date,Name,Engineer FROM table_name WHERE OrderID = '12136' GROUP BY Name,Engineer,Date;
```

Comment: Error Message: ORders_P3Header.HasEngineer is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Vladut - Try now change has been added

Comment: Read the question, he wants `Date, Name and Enginner`